# referenced values are lost with stack frame collapse

Tags: c, pointers, struct, linked-list, stack

I am currently attempting to load values from an array into a stack data structure that I have implemented with a linked list. In my push() function I create each new node in my linked list through the use of a pointer so that they do not disappear when the push() stack frame collapses and control returns to reverse(). However, even though I am passing information through the use of pointers, the item I am referencing appears not be returning, as I keep getting NULL values in the calling function despite getting valid values in the called function. Why is this information not returning to my calling function?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct Node
{
    char data;
    struct Node* next;
};

void push(char x, struct Node* tp)
{
    struct Node* temp = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node*));
    temp->data = x;
    temp->next = tp;
    tp=temp;
    printf("\ntp points to %p", tp);
}

void reverse (char c[])
{
    struct Node* tp = NULL;
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    while (c[i] != '\0')
    {
        push(c[i], tp);
        printf("\ntp points to %p", tp);
        i++;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    char c[] = {"coolio"};
    printf("\n%s", c);
    reverse(c);
}
```

Comment: you are passing a pointer by value. it does not update the tp variable in the reverse method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `push` cannot change `tp` that you pass it from `reverse`, because `tp` is passed by value. Change the function to return the value to be assigned to `tp`, like this:

```
struct Node* push(char x, struct Node* tp) {
    ... // your code here
    return temp;
}
```

The call should look like this:

```
while (c[i] != '\0') {
    tp = push(c[i], tp);
    printf("\ntp points to %p", (void*)tp);
    i++;
}
```

Note that using `%p` requires a cast to `void*`.

[Demo.](https://ideone.com/iZ37yD)